# How to make a netctl profile for a TAP device?

Tags: networking, configuration, netctl, tap

Seeking to make a `netctl` profile for a tap device. Here is the info I was given about the connection.

```
GATEWAY=192.168.117.1  
DNS=192.168.117.1  
BROADCAST=255.255.255.255 **or** 192.168.117.255 (*I was given both of these different values*)  
PREFIX=31  
STATIC IP ADDRESS=192.168.117.2/24  
TYPE=TAP
```

Netctl includes some examples. I used the one I found in `examples/tuntap`:

```
Description='Example tuntap connection'
Interface=tun0
Connection=tuntap
Mode='tun'
User='nobody'
Group='nobody'

## Example IP configuration
#IP=static
#Address='10.10.1.2/16'
```

Here is the profile I came up with:

```
Description='My tap connection'
Interface=tap0
Connection=tuntap
Mode='tap'
User='nobody'
Group='nobody'
IP=static
Address='192.168.117.2/24'
UsePeerDNS=true
DefaultRoute=true
SkipDAD=yes
DHCPReleaseOnStop=yes
```

#### Questions

- Do I need to specify the broadcast address or gateway?
- Is a prefix needed (and what is prefix 31)?
- Is there anything else I have overlooked?

Comment: Note that `tap` is a level 2 device, so you typically put them inside a bridge (which can also be configured in netctl). If you don't use a bridge, there's really to reason to use a tap device instead of a tun device (tap will incur additional overhead). Most applications (you didn't say which application creates your) can be configured to provide both tun or tap interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Do I need to specify the broadcast address or gateway?

From the looks of this article/thread titled: [[SOLVED] Static IP wired connection doesn't work with netctl](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161263) the broadcast address can be incorporated into the static IP's definition.

For example, they provided you with this:

> BROADCAST=255.255.255.255 **or** 192.168.117.255 (*I was given both of these different values*)

I'd assume that the 2nd one, 192.168.117.255, is in fact correct, which would be a /24 mask, hence your `Address=` already has it:

```
Address='192.168.117.2/24'
```

> 2. Is a prefix needed (and what is prefix 31)?

Prefixes or, prefix lengths, are described here in these two articles titled:

- [How do prefix-lists work?](http://blog.ine.com/2007/12/26/how-do-prefix-lists-work/)
- [Working with IP Addresses - The Internet Protocol Journal - Volume 9, Number 1](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/press/internet-protocol-journal/back-issues/table-contents-12/ip-addresses.html)

*excerpt*

> The prefix length is just a shorthand way of expressing the subnet mask. The prefix length is the number of bits set in the subnet mask; for instance, if the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, there are 24

This table shows how they're calculated:

[image: ss1]

So in your case, this information is a bit confusing. Your network address appears to be /24, but your prefix length is 31 bits. In either case, I'd ignore the 31 for the time being, and go with the /24.

> 3. Is there anything else I have overlooked?

Everything else in your example profile appears to check out. You should be good to go.

#### References

- [netctl-profile man page](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpagesman/netctl.profile.5.en)
- [netctl wiki page - ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl)